# how to increment on mouse wheel by 1 regardless of the scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to increment the number by one no matter how long the user mouse wheel scrolls. It increases by 1 if I move the mouse wheel a little but jumps if i use the mouse wheel longer. How would I increment by one regardless?

```
 const [number, setnumber] = useState(1);
  const listener = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setnumber(number + 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", listener);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", listener);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <h2>Number wheel</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **stopImmediatePropagation**:

```
const [number, setnumber] = useState(1);

  const listener = e => {
    setnumber(number + 1);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", listener);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <h2>Number wheel</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-surf-qxerb?file=/src/App.js

PS: But this will make your code (ability to change the initial number of "number") to not work after the number is changed to "number + 1".

Comment: please, a) don't add another event listener on every render, and b) never ever remove them; clean up behind yourself.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the tips. I am fairly new to react. So, regarding (a): the listener shouldn't be inside useEffect? (Because every time "number" changes, it will re-render the component and the hook will add the event listener again). And for (b) I never heard about it. Could you point me to some direction to better understand this? And for (c) is it related to the code or it was just not necessary since we all are trying to learn here? Thanks again ;)

Comment: e.stopImmediatePropagation() It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but has some lag into it. But does the job.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [number, setnumber] = useState(1);
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(null);

  const listener = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    setIsScrolling(
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Run the callback
        setnumber(number + 1);
      }, 50)
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", listener);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", listener);
    };
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-johnson-44t52?file=/src/App.js:76-754)